# UAAppReviewManager Rate Function Not Working on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, appirater, uaappreviewmanager

Hey Stackoverflow People,

I'm working on implementing the `UAAppReviewManager` tool developed by Urban Apps (which is basically a super version of `Appirater`) into my app to have a rating and feedback function. I have devices (running iOS 5/6) where I've tested the Rate feature of the tool and its been able to properly redirect the user to the App Store after they select `Rate the App` from the pop-up dialogue, but for devices using iOS 7, it redirects the user to the App Store app and displays a pop-up saying the following:

`The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be "ax.itunes.apple.com" which could put your confidential information at risk.`

Has anybody used this tool on iOS 7 and encountered this message before? If so, does anyone know what the workaround is? It seems iOS 7 processes things differently underneath with URLs and I'm not doing anything different or specific for earlier versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the developer of [UAAppReviewManager](http://github.com/UrbanApps/UAAppReviewManager). iOS 7 does not allow this url anymore so it was changed to a new value for iOS 7 in UAAppReviewManager. Update to the most recent (0.1.3) as of this writing and you should be fine